# Usage of object pronoun with the verb "buy"

Tags: verbs

In the sentence "I'll buy her a present", why can't it be "I'll buy a present to her"? If both are correct, is there a reason to why it is more common to see the first one?

Comment: You can't use *to her,* but you can use *for her.*

Comment: _Buy_ is not a bitransitive verb like _bring_; it doesn't always have a separate receiver. If there is a receiver for something that you buy, it's assumed to be you. If your intention is to give it to someone, then that person can be mentioned in a benefactive _for_ clause, though that's true for any English sentence with an agent subject -- _I walked 20 miles for Bill_ is grammatical and doesn't transfer 20 miles to Bill. [However, since _she_ winds up with the _present_, the Dative Alternation can apply, and you can get _buy her a present_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, using an indirect object with to buy, you have to use "for" as the separating preposition instead of "to". This makes your sentence:

> I'll buy a present for her.